# how to add a .net framework 4 prerequisite in installshield project file

Tags: installshield

> how to add a .net framework 4 prerequisite in install shield project file,i am using install shield admin studio 10.5.Can i try to create boost-rapper.

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial: Adding Setup Prerequisites to InstallShield package](http://shieldmaster.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/tutorial-adding-setup-prerequisites-to-installshield-package/)